# Untyped contiguous memory container

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl

I am writing an event bus and I need to have an std::vector of dynamic containers. The containers themselves are not type-aware but the storage and retrieval of objects from them is type-aware and so each container is guaranteed to have objects of the same type. (There is a mapping of types to indices).

I was wondering if there is an STL or boost facility that would help with this issue. I would like to avoid using placement new and handle alignment directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::raw_storage_iterator` and maybe also `std::get_temporary_buffer` may help. They are lower level than `std::vector` though. See [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/raw_storage_iterator) for example.

Answer (score 0):

boost::any solves most of these issues but the caller needs to know the type.

Comment: The data wouldn't be stored contiguously though.